# How do i use the same user control in two different modules

Tags: c#, vb.net, user-controls, dotnetnuke

I have two different Modules .Am using dnn.Want i want is to register the user control(.ascx) from one module to diffrent module.

```
<%@ Register Src="~/DesktopModules/DMS/DMS.PatientDiagnosis/Procedures.ascx" TagName="Procedures" TagPrefix="UC" %>
```

use the control in different page:

```
<UC:Procedures id="UCProcedures" runat="server"></UC:Procedures>
```

I tried this.But am not able to call the method from `Procedures.ascx` page

To call method:

```
 UCProcedures.BindFunction = ViewState("dtSelectedProcedure")
 UCProcedures.BindSelectedProcedures(True)
```

But not able to call `BindFunction` and `BindSelectedProcedures`

Comment: Do you get a compile error? Are the BindFunction/Select methods public?

Comment: @HansDerks yes they are public.I don't get them in intellisence

Comment: Can you show the code of the Procedures.ascx with the UCProcedures control and the code of the code behind of UCProcedures? I tried it with an example and it seemed to work

Comment: updated the qus.Have u tried to register the user control from diffrent module?

Comment: I tried to explain how it works on my part in the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my main module:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Pers.ascx.cs" Inherits="Specialist_Pers" %>
<%@ Register src="~/DesktopModules/AgendaPlanner/AgendaPlanner.ascx" tagname="AgendaPlanner" tagprefix="uc1" %>
<uc1:AgendaPlanner ID="AgendaPlanner1" runat="server" />
```

In my code behind in the main

```
public partial class Specialist_Pers : DotNetNuke.Entities.Modules.PortalModuleBase
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AgendaPlanner1.SetAgenda();
    }
}
```

My AgendaPlanner also inherits from **PortalModuleBase**

```
public partial class DesktopModules_AgendaPlanner_AgendaPlanner : PortalModuleBase
{
    public void SetAgenda()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: i have Public Class PatientEChart
        Inherits PortalModuleBase

Comment: AgendaPlanner.ascx is this user control in different module

Comment: Yes, Pers is one module and the AgendaPlanner is a different module. And the Pers ascx has the AgendaPlanner.ascx as usercontrol declared